# error no resource identifier found for attribute 'indeterminateTint' in package 'android'

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to create an XML `ProgressBar`.
When i add the attributes `android:indeterminateTint` and `android:progressBackgroundTint` to the `ProgressBar` i'm getting the error `error no resource identifier found for attribute 'indeterminateTint' in package 'android'` when i compile the project.
I'm using Eclipse if that maters.

The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loader_animation"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="#ffffff"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: That attribute was added in API 21. Is your project targeting API 21?

Comment: @ChristianGöllner Yes it is

Comment: then I would try the usual Eclipse stuff. Build -> Clean -> All projects. Can't remember anything else that could be the problem.

Comment: Also, don't forget that you have to target API 21 in AndroidManifest.xml and also in the project properties.

Comment: What do you mean by `project properties`?

Comment: When in eclipse, right click your project -> properties -> Android -> Target -> Choose API 21.

Comment: @ChristianGöllner maybe i should open new question for that, but i'm currently using `Android 4.4.2`. Do i need to change in the Java build path to `Android 5.0` in order to use `API 21`?

Comment: Yes, you need to change it to Android 5.0 which is API 21.

Comment: I set target API to 21.. But still i am getting this error